# A simple question about Hatcher's notation (abuse?) in Algebraic Topology when defining coproducts.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, summation, differential-topology, cw-complexes

This is a straightforward question, but not one that Hatcher clarifies:

Hatcher likes to write the disjoint union of topological spaces with infix $\coprod $. This works well enough, but there's a certain level of ambiguity interpreting his expression of form

\begin{align}
A \underset{i} \coprod B_i 
\end{align}

which he enjoys using at very critical points in his book (such as when he constructs cellular complexes).

---

**(Q.1)**: Have a finite index $i \in \left( I =  \{ 1, 2, \cdots, n\}\right)$. Then does Hatcher imply

\begin{align}
A \underset{i} \coprod B_i  = A \coprod B_1 \coprod B_2 \coprod \cdots \coprod B_n \quad \quad \quad \quad\; \; \;  \quad \quad \quad \text{(Case 1)}
\end{align}

or does he strangely imply

\begin{align}
A \underset{i} \coprod B_i  = \bigg(A \, B_1  \bigg) \coprod \bigg( A \,B_2  \bigg) \coprod \cdots \coprod  \bigg(A \, B_n \bigg) \; \; \; \; \; \quad   \; \text{(Case 2)}
\end{align}

I'd assume (Case 1) is true (I haven't seen him define concatenation) but I want to check since textbooks will switch from abusing notation (and not explaining when) to having definitions like compactness in which every word counts.

---

**(Q.2)** I prefer extending $+$ to topological spaces and using it to denote the coproduct. I'll also denote $\bigg( B_1 + B_2 + \cdots B_n  = \sum \limits_i B_i \bigg)$. Then is it valid to rewrite Hatcher and have

\begin{align}
A \underset{i} \coprod B_i  = A + \sum \limits_i B_i \quad \text{(Rewrite 1)}
\end{align}

If (Rewrite 1) holds, then there is a bit off oddness in Hatcher's abuse of notation, as you would have something analogous to stating $\bigg( A + \sum \limits_i B_i = A \sum \limits_i B_i \bigg) $. This could be reconciled by thinking of $ + B_i $ as being a string that you prolong $i$ times to form the expression.

---

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez You first example is using $\prod$ to denote multiplication over some field where concatenation also denotes multiplication. Trivial, and has absolutely nothing to do with what I asked. Not possible to generalize to $\coprod$ which operates in analogue to $\sum$. Neither of the comments you wrote address the question, in which Hatcher is combining concatenation with a sum (disjoint union) of topological spaces.

Comment: Alright, expanding out your example: $12 \prod_{k=1}^7 = 12 \; (1!) (2!) (3!) (4!) (5!) (6!) (7!)$. Again, completely different. Middle school algebra. What Hatcher states is more analogous to writing $12 \sum_{k=1}^7 = 12  \left( (1!) + (2!) + (3!) + (4!) + (5!) + (6!) + (7!) \right)$. Except we aren't in middle school and distributing then concatenating 12 to the rest of the expression has no interpretation. Kindly explain what Hatcher means by $A \coprod_i B_i$. Here he's combining concatenation with a topological sum. Since part of his definition is vacuous, it has to stand for something.

Comment: What would $\mathbb{R}P^2S^6$ mean?

Comment: case 2 indeed does not parse, since for two arbitrary sets $AB$ does not apriori mean anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1 is the case. The notation is pretty much standard and I would not call it "abuse" by any measure. For reference, consider the following quote from page 5 of AT, right from the definition of cell complexes you mention: "Thus as a set, $X^n = X^{n - 1} \coprod_\alpha e_\alpha^n$ where each $e_\alpha^n$ is an open $n$-disk." *Clearly* the only sensible interpretation is as $X^n = X^{n - 1} \sqcup \coprod_\alpha e_\alpha^n$, as I am sure anybody familiar with CW-complexes will gladly confirm :)